# Rendering a component onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I'm rank new to React and to Javascript in general. Thus the question.

I've a list of images being displayed in a React component. What I'm trying to achieve is to define a method to handle the `onClick` method on any of these images and render a new component as an overlay. This is my code:

```
class Viewer extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images : ImageList
    };

  }

  componentDidMount(){

  }
  handleClick(mediaId, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    render(){
      <MyNewComponent  mediaId=mediaId />
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="image-viewer">
          <ul className="list-inline">
            {this.state.images.map(function (image) {
              return (<li key={image.mediaId}><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(image.mediaId, event)}><img src={image.src}
                                                               className="img-responsive img-rounded img-thumbnail"
                                                               alt={image.mediaId}/></a></li>);
            })}

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Viewer;
```

This clearly is wrong and throws up a bunch of errors. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of an overlay? A full screen one? And what contents do you need in them?

Comment: @PraneshRavi an overlay of the size of the image itself. This overlay has to carry a form input and submit buttom. I need to pass the mediaId with an user Id to the api call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how to handle the `click` event and show the overlay

```
class Viewer extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images : ImageList,
      mediaId : 0
    };
    // Bind `this`
    // See "Binding to methods of React class" link below
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){ }

  handleClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the value of the `data-id` attribute <a data-id="XX">
    var mediaId = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-id'].value;
    // Set the state to re render
    this.setState({ mediaId }); // ES6 shortcut
    // this.setState({ mediaId: mediaId }); // Without shortcut
  }

  render(){
    // Set a variable which contains your newComponent or null
    // See "Ternary operator" link below
    // See "Why use null expression" link below
    var overlay = this.state.mediaId ? <MyNewComponent  mediaId={this.state.mediaId} /> : null;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="image-viewer">
          { overlay }
          <ul className="list-inline">
            {this.state.images.map(image => {
              return (<li key={image.mediaId}><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} data-id={image.mediaId}><img src={image.src}
                                                               className="img-responsive img-rounded img-thumbnail"
                                                               alt={image.mediaId}/></a></li>);
            }).bind(this)}

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Viewer;
```

---

#### Documentation

- [React and ES6 - Binding to methods of React class](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html)
- [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [Why use `null` expression](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)

Comment: this looks great, but could you comment the code a bit with some explanation. I'm really a newbie to the world of javascript and find myself at a complete loss.

Comment: I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined' any idea why that's happening.

Comment: Fixed the error. I had to pass `this` to the map function. Putting it here as it might help others.

Comment: I had some documentation and comments. I fixed as well the `this` issue, thanks.